# Test Class Data for PlatformEventUsageMetric

Tags: code-coverage, platform-event, test-setup, usagemetrics

I have a simple, invocable class to query delivered platform events using the PlatformEventUsageMetric object and it is working in flow, but I'm not sure how to create a test class for it if I can't create data for the object. Any information on what to do when needing to test an object that has system-only generated records?

My apex that needs code coverage

```
public without sharing class PlatformInvoke {

  @InvocableMethod(label='Get Platform Events' description='Returns the list of delivered platform events with StartDate in the past 32 days')
  public static List<List<SObject>> getPlatformEvents() {
    Date past32Days = Date.today().addDays(-32);
    List<List<SObject>> platformEvents = new List<List<SObject>>();
    List<SObject> events = [SELECT Name, StartDate FROM PlatformEventUsageMetric WHERE Name = 'PLATFORM_EVENTS_DELIVERED' AND StartDate >= :past32Days];
    platformEvents.add(events);
    return platformEvents;
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried creating a static resource and using `Test.loadData()`?

Comment: wrap the SOQL in a selector class and mock that class in your testmethod to return mocked SObjects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get around this issue by creating a helper class that sent the query metrics to my invocable method. I then invoked the helper class and my original method in the test class.

```
public without sharing class PlatformInvoke {

  @InvocableMethod(label='Get Platform Events' description='Returns the list of delivered platform events with StartDate in the past 32 days')
  public static List<List<SObject>> getPlatformEvents() {

    List<List<SObject>> platformEvents = new List<List<SObject>>();
    List<PlatformEventUsageMetric> metrics = SnowytreePlatformInvoke.queryMetrics();
    platformEvents.add(metrics);
    return platformEvents;
  }


  //Helper class for unit testing

    public static List<PlatformEventUsageMetric> queryMetrics() {
        // Perform the actual query and return the results
        Date past32Days = Date.today().addDays(-32);
        return [SELECT Name, StartDate FROM PlatformEventUsageMetric WHERE Name = 'PLATFORM_EVENTS_DELIVERED' AND StartDate >= :past32Days];
    }
}
```

And the test class:

```
@isTest
private class PlatformInvokeTest {
    @isTest
    static void testGetPlatformEvents() {
        // Call the invocable method
        List<List<SObject>> platformEventsResult = PlatformInvoke.getPlatformEvents();

        // Assert that the result is not null
        System.assertNotEquals(null, platformEventsResult, 'Result should not be null');

        // Add additional assertions based on specific requirements
    }
}
```